# Why does anxiety medication work?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, anxiety, medication

It seems really odd to me that anxiety medication can work, because I can't understand how a medication can alter a feeling.

My understanding is that the idea of anxiety medication is to alter neurotransmitters and activity in certain areas of the brain in order to change how a person experiences anxiety. For example for someone who experiences anxiety an ideal medication (very informally) would be a medication reducing activity of amygdala.

What I find very odd about this approach is that I don't believe feelings are just chemicals, i.e it dosen't make sense to me that altering some neurotransmitters in the brain can have a psychological impact on a person but only a physiological. I don't understand how someone can fear a something (for example a spider) and altering its brain chemistry and activity can make someone not feeling afraid of a spider.

So does anxiety medication have impact only on the physiological symptoms of anxiety?

Comment: `What I find very odd about this approach is that I don't believe feelings are just chemicals`. Perhaps you should add why you don't believe that. It's not obvious to me why anyone would not believe that.